# Serial Port (COM1) becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, serial

Originally I made a POS application using Excel/VB.  Everything worked A-OK, especially the serial communication with the POS display pole.  Here's an example of the code by which I had the application communicate:

```
Function Send2Display(ln1$, Optional ln2$)
    On Error GoTo theEnd
    Dim ln1Space As Byte, ln2Space As Byte
    ln1 = Left(ln1, 20): ln1Space = 20 - Len(ln1)
    ln2 = Left(ln2, 20): ln2Space = 20 - Len(ln2)
    Open "COM1:" For Output As #1
        ' Write lines and then set cursor to start
        Print #1, ln1; Spc(ln1Space); ln2; Spc(ln2Space)
        Print #1, Chr$(&H1B)
theEnd:
    Err.Clear: Close #1
End Function
```

As I said, this worked ok.  Now however I've moved the POS application over to RoR and I've had to make a Java applet for the purpose of communicating with the display pole.  The applet works fine save for the following problem:

I'm not sure what the *cause* of it is, but at a given point in time Java reports that I'm using "an incorrect||missing function" when sending data to the COM port.  I have to close the application (web page), then disable COM1 in the Device Manager then re-enable it.  Then when I load the web page again it starts working.  See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025052/191741) for the Java code and JNLP.

If the COM port is unresponsive to the web app I can load the old Excel file and it will still work.  I'm at a loss as to why it won't work for the Java applet.

Comment: "POS application using Excel/VB" ← that's the very definition of horror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, turns out I had installed the display pole as a printer way back and that was what was tying up the COM1 port.  I removed it and so far I haven't encountered any issues.

Comment: you can mark your own answer as the solution